# Transportation p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m with available source is more than destination

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to solve a transportation problem which is different from classical transportation problem.

In this case sum of items at the sources are greater than sum items required at the destination.

Please point me to some direction on how to solve this kind of problem. Every where I look I find classical transportation problem.

Comment: You have a better chance to get a good answer at either http://math.stackexchange.com or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform your problem and apply the "original" algorithm:
Add an "artificial" target node sucht that its demand is equal to the overall surplus and all transportation costs to this node are zero.